# Equality operator bevaiour for dynamically passed string values in java

Tags: java, string, string-pool, equality-operator

```
public class EqualsCheck {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner sc1= new Scanner(System.in);
        String s1 = sc.next();
        String s2 = sc1.next();
        equalCheck(s1,s2);
    }

    private static void equalCheck(String s1, String s2) {
        //Using Assignment
        System.out.println(s1 == s2);

        //Using equals

        System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));

        //Printing HashCode

        System.out.println("s1 :"+s1.hashCode()+" s2: "+s2.hashCode());
    }
}
```

Passed string are :

```
 s1 = "abc";
 s2 = "abc";
```

If I do a `s1==s2`, it returns `false`. Why string pooling doesn't work here.

Comment: s1.equals(s2) returns true as expected.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question has been answered on SO a million times before

Comment: "Using Assignment" there is no assignment here. This is using *identity*.

Comment: There's no string pooling involved whatsoever. You're reading two new strings from `sc`.

Answer (score 1):

String pooling doesn't work here because you're not putting strings in the string pool.

This doesn't happen automatically for strings constructed at runtime. You would need to call `String.intern()` to do so.